# Wireless hard block on ASUS N61Jv (ar9285)

Tags: wireless, asus, atheros

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu and noticed that my wifi is disabled.

In try menu it says that my hardware switch is disabled, but there is no physical switch on N61Jv. I tried <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> which should work as "hardware switch", but it didn't help. Then I tried to do `rfkill list all`:

```
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

The `rfkill ublock all` command doesn't change anything there. I know that pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> changes "Soft blocked:" to "yes". I don't have any idea what to do now.

edit:

```
gksu jockey-gtk
```

didn't show any drivers, here are my outputs:

**lscpi:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 325M] (rev a2)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

**sudo lshw -class NETWORK:**

```
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 48:5d:60:37:08:62
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.2.0-27-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:e8800000-e880ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: 1e:cb:7d:5c:b5:e4
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:51 memory:e3800000-e383ffff ioport:7000(size=128)
```

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: Isn't there a switch for wifi on the left side of the laptop?
My girlfriend's N61JV has one...

Answer (score 1):

No. Fn + F2 should change hardware state. Probably you didn't install the closed source driver required for your card.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gksu jockey-gtk`. This will search for additional drivers required for your system from internet. Activate them.

If no drivers listed there. Please edit your question with output of `lspci` and `sudo lshw -class NETWORK`

Update from: [Atheros AR9485 wireless card doesn't work in an ASUS K53E](https://askubuntu.com/q/121487/35775)

According to the answer, you need to install `linux-backports-modules-cw` and update network manger after wards.  Give it a try.

**`linux-backports-modules-cw` is specific to kernel.**

- First execute `uname -r`. Get your kernel version.
- Open software centre and search for `linux-backports-modules-cw`. Now carefully choose the correct version according to kernel version. Say your kernel name is `3.2.0-27-generic`. So you should download `linux-backports-modules-cw-3.3-3.2.0-27-generic 3.2.0-27.xx`
- Update network-manager.
- Now reboot

The compitable cards are listed here http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/WLAN/Linux-backports-modules#Enthaltene-Treiber